# How to add multiple views with recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an multiple views in my screen.

**How to include my layout content in top of the screen and recyclerview in my bottom of the screen?**

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of top layout you want to add.

If you want to add image or view pager with sliding images, then its better to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `AppBarLayout` inside `CoordinatorLayout`, then Add your RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/avatar_bg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="160dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                    <!-- Here you can add your header layout only if its not too big-->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/myprofile_avatar"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_avatar_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_avatar_size" />



                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/profile_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by overriding this method,**getItemViewType(int position)** this specifies which layout to inflate for a perticular position of the recycler view

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return LAYOUT_TYPE_0;
        else if (position == 1)
            return LAYOUT_TYPE_1;
        else
            return LAYOUT_TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```

here is the **complete adapter code**

```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

        public static final int LAYOUT_TYPE_0 = 0;
        public static final int LAYOUT_TYPE_1 = 1;
        public static final int LAYOUT_TYPE_ITEM = 2;


        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == LAYOUT_TYPE_0) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_0, parent, false);
                return new LayoutPos0(view);
            } else if (viewType == LAYOUT_TYPE_1) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_1, parent, false);
                return new LayoutPos1(view);
            } else {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_common, parent, false);
                return new LayoutCommon(view);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {            
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return LAYOUT_TYPE_0;
            else if (position == 1)
                return LAYOUT_TYPE_1;
            else
                return LAYOUT_TYPE_ITEM;
        }



        public class LayoutPos0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                //your code goes here
        }

        private class LayoutPos1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        }

        private class LayoutCommon extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{          
    }

 @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 100;
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way, to include multiple view :

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);

         }
    }
```

Refer [RecyclerView with multiple view type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply amit. But when i make an action from top of the content , bottom of the recyclerview content to be focused into the top of the screen. How to do it?

Comment: USE recyclerview.requestFocus();